# Displaying a stream of images with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

The current solution looks like this:

```
//paintlabel.h
class PaintLabel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PaintLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void setImage(char *img_ptr, QSize img_size, int pitch);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    QImage image;

}

//paintlabel.cpp

PaintLabel::PaintLabel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
}

void PaintLabel::setImageLive(char *img_ptr, QSize img_size, int pitch)
{
    image = QImage((uchar *)img_ptr, img_size.width(), img_size.height(), pitch, QImage::Format_RGB32).scaled(this->size());
    update();  
}

void PaintLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);
    if (!image.isNull()) {
        const QPoint p = QPoint(0,0);
        painter.drawImage(p, image);
    }
    painter.end();
}
```

I expect 20-40 frames per second. The problem is, that the performance scales really bad with size. With the size around fullHD the painting takes 1-2 ms. But if I resize it to 4k, it gets awfully laggy (16 ms painting). Is there any way to implement the same functionality but with less resource consumption?

Theoretically, if I change the parent class to QOpenGLWidget, the QPainter runs with hardware acceleration. But doing it, it runs even slower.

Comment: In OpenGL you can use double buffering to avoid this. May be you can have 2 PaintLabel, and don't show the new image until it's loaded.

Comment: The double buffering does not really change the fact, that the rendering is extremely slow. I'd estimate it 3-5 fps, while the camera produces 25.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly one of the limiting factors in your code seems to be the `scaled()` function. Try taking it out and you should see some speed-up.

Other problem is simply the limitation of performance of QImage. Refer this question for more information. [How can QPainter performance be improved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512155)

> QPainter will use software rasterizer to draw QImage instances.

refer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-graphics.html for more information.

You cant go for `QPixmap` since your entire buffer changes each frame as well.

You can try using the `QOpenGLPaintDevice` to make the `QPainter` use hardware acceleration. Another approach you tried is `QOpenGLWidget`.

> QOpenGLWidget - A painter can also be opened on a QOpenGLWidget. This is provided as a convenience, since technically this is no different than using QOpenGLPaintDevice.

refer the same qt link above.

So yes this should technically be faster, BUT since you are resizing the `Widget` thereby resizing the `OpenGL Viewport`, the underneath buffers get re-made each time. Hence the slowdown is much more. Do note that QOpenGLWidget handles some functions such as `glViewport()` by itself. This is not useful when you are trying to optimize performance.

Here are a couple of suggestions

1. I believe the major issue is the handling of QImage. I suggest you setup your own OpenGL Scene, simply with one quad to render a texture, and try writing to the texture each frame. The scaling will be handled on the GPU so it will surely be faster .
2. Alternatively you can use `glDrawPixels()` to render the image from host memory (RAM) to the frame buffer. Although this will not handle scaling for you. refer to https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml for more information.

I am currently using QGLWidget and custom OpenGL texture and draw calls to achieve a fast update (>60 FPS). I have observed this to be about 8x to 10x faster than the QImage / Qpixmap method. Please note that my texture size never surpasses 700x700. Also my Image is always stored on GPU memory and updated by mapped CUDA kernel.

You should definitely see a speed-up but I can't guarantee it will meet your FPS requirement.